# Will two concurrent updates on same Oracle 11 row cause deadlock or failure to update?

Tags: database, oracle, concurrency, deadlock

I have a microservice that tries to update a row in an Oracle 11 Database by issuing two calls in parallel. These calls are supposed to update different columns. Will it cause deadlock? Or one call will lock the given row and other call will wait for the lock to be released?

Comment: Do you want to lock data or are you having a real problem with a deadlock? Could you give some more context about what you're expecting to happen?

Comment: You can try this very easily to see the results.  Open to sqlplus sessions and do the updates.

Comment: No not having deadlocks. First call updates the data but the other call does not do anything and returns back.

Comment: Could you share some code? Are you actually locking the row or are these just two updates without locking?

Comment: These two are simple update calls. No locking is done from code (Java) side.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a *deadlock*.  A deadlock occurs when two processes lock the same rows in a different order.  In your case, if only on row is modified, the second session will *wait* for the first one (i.e. the one that first ran the `update` statement) to either `commit` or `rollback`. Then it'll perform its own `update`.

Comment: Our code is in Java and the calls are fired by creating two threads.Currently, first call that locks the row is able to successfully update the row. But second call returns back without doing anything. Can that be a problem with Java code or maybe Oracle DB configuration?

Comment: I don't know anything about "microservice" nor the way it "issues calls". I speak a little bit of Oracle and understand `update that_table set some_column = some_value where some_condition`. Maybe your "call" contains a mechanism which *returns* without doing anything if its update is not successful (i.e. it find the row locked by another session).